# Can IOS devices stream m3u8 segmented video from the local file system using html5 video and phonegap/cordova?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova, video-streaming

I'm using phonegap/cordova 2.1 and my app has locally stored assets (on the device) which need to be encrypted on build and decrypted in memory when used in execution. The app is for iPad only.

For the videos I want to implement something similar to http://codebycoffee.com/2012/01/08/decrypting-http-streaming-video-with-nsurlprotocol where mediafilesegmenter is used to segment and encrypt each video file and then a custom encrypted file url protocol serves the key for each video when the video player requests the m3u8 file.

My problem is that I can't seem to play m3u8 files by using the html5 video tag and phonegap/cordova. I have even created unencrypted video segments with the use of mediafilesegmenter as a test. These can be played by opening the m3u8 file with VLC in OSX but when using the video tag in phonegap/cordova I get 'loading...' message followed by a popup saying "The operation could not be completed"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK so it turns out that m3u8 files have to be served over HTTP and I have gone down the route of bundling a cocoahttpserver https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer in with the app.  This way I can request the video streams with:

```
<video src="http://127.0.0.1:12345/path.m3u8"
```

Comment: cool. are you able to serve files from the iOS file system ? For me it only works when I setDocumentRoot to the app bundle for some reason. When I choose NSDocumentDirectory or NSCachesDirectory it doesn't work.

Comment: how can i create m3u8 file from NSData and keep in cocoahttpserver? @TrekCzar