# How to download HLS/M3U8 chunks in ios device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http-live-streaming, offline-mode, m3u8

How to store locally m3u8 file with all chunks (.ts) from url in ios device.
If possible so how to do it?

I have developing functionality like.. Download .m3u8 file with chunks(.ts) in ios local storage then after modify .m3u8 and will play offline mode.

Please help me if have any kind of solution for above question.

Comment: I have done it. 1. Setup Local Server with root directory. 2. Download index file  and store in  local server root directory. 3. Download each of segment (.ts) one by one and  local server root directory, segment path is get from  index file.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can do this is to set up an HTTP server to serve the files locally after you've downloaded them.

Here are some related answers: [Can IOS devices stream m3u8 segmented video from the local file system using html5 video and phonegap/cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13271624/can-ios-devices-stream-m3u8-segmented-video-from-the-local-file-system-using-htm)